# Django - CSRF Tokens for authenticated and unauthenticated users?

Tags: django, api, token, forms-authentication, csrf

I was wondering if CSRF tokens for Django are generated automatically for **both** authenticated users and unauthenticated users? I am curious because I would like to make an API for posting form data so that any user -authenticated or unauthenticated users can be able to make a post call to the API endpoint. But I was wondering if I have to "attach" the CSRF token to the header for each user? (Implying that unauthenticated users would also have a CSRF token)

Answer (score 0):

Both authenticated and unauthenticated users require a valid CSRF token when using Django's default authentication mechanism. The token is rotated when a user logs in.

Whether you need a token isn't so much dependent on if the user is authenticated, but it is dependent on the authentication mechanism. If the authentication uses sessions/cookies to authenticate the user, an attacker may use the session information that's implicitly send with each request to forge a request and perform some action that the victim is authorized to do. On the other hand, if you use e.g. token authentication, the token has to be send explicitly with each request, and an attacker can't know the token or forge a request that uses the token.

Comment: Thanks! I am still confused why a csrf token is needed when a person is not logged in (cookies are not present). Aren't most operations "safe" if a person is not logged in?